# LOCK TABLES can cause deadlocks in InnoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

From MySQL manual ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html ):

> To reduce the possibility of deadlocks, use transactions rather than LOCK TABLES statements

How deadlocks are possible by using LOCK TABLES in InnoDB?

For example, if I write

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 WRITE, t3 WRITE, t4 WRITE;
... do something with tables t1-t4 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

do I really have to check errors like 1213 every time I execute this script?

Comment: If, at the same time, you lock t1 and use t2, and other user lock t2 and use t1, then you have a dead lock, because both are waiting for the other to release the table.

Comment: You know that `LOCK TABLES` downgrades InnoDB basiclly to MyiSAM and execute much slower for multiple threads (read connections) then InnoDB can when using `SET autocommit=0;` in combination with `TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`

Comment: @Felippe Duarte What do you mean by "use t2"? A READ lock? What if I'm using only WRITE locks like in my example.

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I'm not concerned about performance. I have a situation where I want to make things as simple as possible and LOCK TABLES feels much more intuitive to me than using transactions with paranoid level error checking.

Comment: How are transactions not intuitive?  Locks are made and maintained to ensure integrity during the transaction. What there is not intuitive?

Comment: So instead of using the database-level concurrency and consistency mechanism, you want to manually lock the tables because deadlocks seem "bad"? A deadlock is just a coping mechanism, a mere warning, not a nuclear meltdown. Having a process that obtained the lock and didn't release it is a nuclear meltdown, and that's not the only thing that can go wrong. Having to repeat a transaction due to a deadlock is a nuisance, but an easy one to deal with.

Comment: @Donnie ROLLBACKs cost time and make things too complicated. For example, if the processing takes 16 seconds a rollback would be a serious problem if the server timeout is 30 seconds. I don't even know if my software is being used with InnoDB or MyISAM. What I need is a privileged access to the tables. Other users can wait or even timeout but this one user must be able to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Furicane I don't think deadlocks are bad but in this case I think LOCK TABLES would be much easier to implement than transactions. Also, I want to understand how things work rather than do like others say.

Comment: Rollbacks only happen on the `ROLLBACK` command and a fatal error that would leave data in an inconsistent state.  In these cases, a rollback is the RIGHT thing to do. I think you don't understand how transactions work very well and are attempting to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make sure to lock *all* the tables you will read or write in one LOCK TABLES statement, you should be able to avoid deadlocks.

The other good reason to avoid using LOCK TABLES if you can use transactions instead is to allow row-level locking. LOCK TABLES only locks at the table level, which means concurrent sessions can't touch any rows in the table, even if your session doesn't need to lock them.

This is a disadvantage for software that needs to allow multiple sessions to access tables concurrently. You're forcing table-level locking, which will put a constraint on your software's throughput, because all sessions that access tables will queue up against each other, and be forced to execute serially.

> What do you mean by "use t2"? A READ lock? What if I'm using only WRITE locks like in my example.

I think he means if you read from table t2. Since you have that table locked for WRITE, that includes blocking any readers of that table as well.  No other session can read or write the table until you UNLOCK.

> I'm not concerned about performance. I have a situation where I want to make things as simple as possible and LOCK TABLES feels much more intuitive to me than using transactions with paranoid level error checking.

You will eventually find a case where you want your software to have good performance. You'll have to become more comfortable using transactions.

Comment: As far as I know, If I LOCK table T1 I can't even read from table T2 without LOCKing T2 too or UNLOCKing T1 first. So the scenario other user suggest in the comments and to which you are referring should not be possible???

Comment: "But if your code references any other tables besides those you locked, then you have a risk of a deadlock." Can you please explain these lines in more detailed way??]

Comment: @RajSaraogi That part of my answer turns out to be wrong, so I removed it. If you LOCK TABLES, you can't make updates to any tables other than those you locked, so there is no way another session can acquire any locks out of order.

Comment: @BillKarwin one of our user currently acquired locks in two tables out of 20 for few minutes, this caused the transactions to go in wait and lot of transactions from other sql users where happening, after killing the process used by the user who acquired lock on table, after that also locks where seen for other queries and our production system went down. Why would have that happened ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Why did the user acquire a lock? Or why do locks block other users? Or why other queries also acquire locks? I think you need to ask a new question, and tell the whole story.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58232910/mysql-debezium-connector-for-rds-in-production-caused-deadlocks/58249997#58249997

Comment: hi @Bill Karwin excellent response +1. If I use LOCK TABLES with autocommit = 0;, innodb_table_locks = 1 (the default) and innodb tables, will deadlocks be detected if any?

Comment: [link](dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html). The documentation says so, but I'm not sure I understood the LOCK TABLES thing correctly in that documentation, thanks in advance @Bill Karwin

Comment: You asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234268/detect-deadlocks-with-lock-tables-with-autocommit-0-and-innodb-tables), and I wrote a more full answer.