# Detect deadlocks with LOCK TABLES with autocommit = 0 and InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, transactions, timeout, innodb, deadlock

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html

> InnoDB is aware of table locks if innodb_table_locks = 1 (the default)
> and autocommit = 0, and the MySQL layer above it knows about row-level
> locks. Otherwise, InnoDB cannot detect deadlocks where **a table lock
> set by a MySQL LOCK TABLES statement** or a lock set by a storage engine
> other than InnoDB is involved. Resolve these situations by setting the
> value of the innodb_lock_wait_timeout system variable.

According to the documentation, I understand that using innodb tables and using LOCK TABLES as indicated below **will detect deadlocks**:

```
SET autocommit=0;
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ, ...;
... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Is this correct or did I misunderstand? Please correct me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a single LOCK TABLES statement to lock all the tables you will access during your transaction, the tables are locked atomically. There is no chance for deadlock.

For example, in the example you included in your question (the example shown in the manual), since you lock tables `t1` and `t2`, a concurrent session that attempts to lock either one of these tables will be blocked. Or if the concurrent session locks them first, then your session will be blocked for *both* table locks. The one who waits will not lock either table until the other unlocks.

If the sessions lock one table at a time, this is not atomic, and if they accumulate locks, then they might lock one table and then be blocked waiting for a lock on the other table. Thus it would be a deadlock.

In fact, they do not accumulate table locks with successive LOCK TABLES statements.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html:

> UNLOCK TABLES explicitly releases any table locks held by the current session. LOCK TABLES implicitly releases any table locks held by the current session before acquiring new locks.

So deadlocks do not occur. If you try to execute one LOCK TABLES after another, you effectively let the other session acquire the table locks that your session held. So no deadlock.

Comment: Great @Bill Karwin, so that paragraph in the documentation is redundant, it's "just ignored", right?

Comment: More or less, yes. But it gets more complex if you introduce other storage engines with row-level locking (e.g. RocksDB). If you have a transaction that accesses locks in multiple tables using different storage engines, you're on your own. But I hope this is rare, and you won't try this unless you're an expert with both storage engines.

Comment: ok, thanks @Bill Karwin +1, I have one last doubt, so if I use ONLY innodb's own row-level locks (i.e. is/ix, next-key lock, etc) deadlock detection is enabled by default, right?

Comment: In the manual page you linked to it says: _"When deadlock detection is enabled (the default)..."_